# venndiagram vs. beamer overlay

Tags: beamer, venn-diagrams

I want [venndiagram](https://ctan.org/pkg/venndiagram) 3sets with beamer overlays.

I tried it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{venndiagram3sets}[
    labelOnlyA={1},
    \only<2->{labelOnlyB={2},}
    \only<3->{labelOnlyC={3}}
    ]
  \end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want the `labelOnlyB`'s 2 and `labelOnlyC`'s 3 appears on second and third overlay - instead I see a plus comma and the string `labelOnlyC=3` on pdf.

How can I do it what I want?

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

```
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[
    labelOnlyA={1},
    labelOnlyB={\only<2->{2}},
    labelOnlyC={\only<3->{3}}
    ]
\end{venndiagram3sets}
```

So the content of `labelOnlyXY` should contain overlay specification.